# How many consecutive positive integers can you make using exactly four instances of the digit '4'?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Starting at 1 (which is 4 - $\sqrt4$ - 4/4), how many consecutive integers can you make using exactly four instances of the digit '4'?

Basic rules:

- Any operator symbol is "free".
- Any printed '4' counts toward your four '4's.
- Other digits are NOT allowed.
- Other characters like letters or miscellaneous punctuation are NOT allowed, unless you can provide some citation of an accepted mathematical definition.

Allowed operators (non-exhaustive):

- + Addition
- - Subtraction or Negation
- * Multiplication
- / Division
- $\sqrt4$ Square root (ignore the implicit '2' there)
- $\sqrt[4]4$ Radical (in this case you've used two '4's)
- ^ Exponentiation
- ! Factorial
- ? Terminal function (4? = 4 + 3 + 2 + 1)
- 44 Concatenation (which in this case consumes two '4's)
- |4| Absolute value
- . Decimal point
- If you can find a way to use calc, trig, matrices, whatever, by all means please do

Comment: Last time I tried this I allowed the `̇ ` operator e.g. `4/.4̇ ` is 36.

Comment: @question_asker Yes, I typoed - it should say `4 * 4 / .4̇`.

Comment: If you allow any other symbol with an accepted mathematical definition, then doesn't that mean we have free and unlimited use of $-e^{i \pi}$, $\ln e$, $-\cos \pi$, and other such digitless ways of constructing 1? It seems like we don't even need the abstruse math of some of the answers below.

Comment: @ruakh I assume that we have access to any mathematical definition but not to any mathematical constant. So, no $\pi$, no $e$, no $i$.

Comment: Can we use floor or ceil?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Answer:

> All of them!

How?

> For every positive integer $n$,$$\underbrace{\sec\arctan}_{n^2-1\text{ times}}\,\frac{44}{44}=n$$otherwise written as$$\sec\arctan(\sec\arctan(...\sec\arctan(\frac{44}{44})))$$so all positive integers can be made with four fours. (Idea from [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18749/12408).)

Comment: Well played sir!

Comment: There goes a whole category of puzzles :). +1

Comment: @Lawrence Only the ones that allow free trig functions!

Comment: You could have left hand side squared and use $\frac{4}{\sqrt{4}}$ for that and $\frac{4}{4}$ for the 1. That way you'd only need $n$ repetitions.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but doesn't the $n^2-1\ times$ include two non-allowed extra digits?

Comment: @question_asker That's shorthand for writing out $\sec\arctan$ that many times. For example, when $n=2$ the expression is $\sec\arctan\sec\arctan\sec\arctan\frac{44}{44}$.

Comment: @question_asker No, you just repeat it that many times.  If $n=2$, then the formula is sec arctan(sec arctan(sec arctan($\frac{44}{44}$)))

Comment: @f'' aha, so you're saying you could express this without the $n^2-1$ at all? that answers my question perfectly, thank you!

Comment: But if `n = 4`, does that not count as fifth instance of 4? The question states  "using exactly four instances of 4", but if your input (which is _used_) is 4, that would make five fours.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter (someone else correct me if I'm wrong here but) I think the 4 in that case would be the *output*. It's only "used" insofar as it tells you how many times to repeat the $sec\ arctan$ bit.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter There wouldn't be a fifth 4 used. When n = 4, the expression has 15 occurrences of sec arctan:  sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan$\frac{44}{44}$

Comment: @question_asker Yes, exactly that

Comment: Aye, I understand that, but let's write `n^2-1` as `4^2-1` and we do have a fifth four.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter - You never *write* `4^2-1`. f"s answer only gives you the "pseudo-code" for how to write it. You would actually write `sec arctan` 15 times, followed by 44/44, i.e. `sec arctan sec arctan sec arctan (...11 more times...) sec arctan 44/44`

Comment: Yeah okay, but you _use_ 4 to write `sec arctan` 15 times. Guess it's a matter of semantics

Comment: @Stephan: His answer is *instructions* for what to write down, not what you should actually write down. Sure, you use $n$ to figure out how many times you should write $\sec\arctan$, but that doesn't mean you ever write down $n$.

Comment: Broken MathJax in Brian J's comment is making the comments look funny, they overflow into the HNQ list...

Comment: @pipe Maybe, maybe not)

Comment: We are all facepalming for him already, no need for him to come back and do it at a later date.

Comment: If we get to throw arbitrary mathematical functions in for free, we could just use $S$, the successor function. This puzzle is way too permissive.

Comment: The comments on this post are [being discussed on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276234/244435).

Comment: @nhgrif It's also [on Puzzling Meta](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4579/comments-overflow-into-right-hand-column).

Comment: sec arctan 44/44 is not 1 no matter how you express it (at best it's 1.00025823112 if you secarctan (44) the divide by 44), therefore not an integer. Sec arctan-ing the second time you already getting something totally different. Or am I missing somthing ?

Comment: @Overmind, for n=1, there will be no sec arctan (since 1^2-1=0). For n=2, there will be 3 sec arctan (2^2-1). And [the result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sec%28tan%5E%28-1%29%28sec%28tan%5E%28-1%29%28sec%28tan%5E%28-1%29%281%29%29%29%29%29%29) is 2.

Answer (score 21):

### Prefix edit

Why not allow the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)? well, let's use it. For the record:

\begin{align}
0!! &= 1 \\
5!! &= 3 \cdot 5 = 15 \\
6!! &= 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 = 48 \\
\end{align}

Also the [choose operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) (also known as binomial coefficient).

## Modular approach

I had some fun doing it the long way, but then I decided to jump into a more modular / exploitable strategy. I will build it for a little bit, so bear with me for now :)

First, let's make the following list with one four:

\begin{align}
2 &= \sqrt 4 \\
3 &= \left(\sqrt 4\right)? \\
4 &= 4 \\
6 &= \left(\sqrt 4\right)?! \\
8 &= 4!! \\
10 &= 4? \\
21 &= \left(\sqrt 4\right)?!? \\
24 &= 4! \\
36 &= \left(4!!\right)? \\
48 &= \left(\left(\sqrt 4\right)?!\right)!! = 6!!\\
55 &= 4??
\end{align}

I can also consider $ 4 = \sqrt 4 + \sqrt 4 $, so there is no need to consider the "extra fours".

From now on, I will use the fancy "one-four" substitution, and maybe some results will use less than four fours. But the translation from a compact equation to a "four-fours" equation is immediate.

Let's consider the following list of two-four numbers (I purposely omit the ones that can be obtained with a signel four):

\begin{align}
0 &= 4 - 4 \\
1 &= \frac{4}{4} \\
5 &= 2 + 3 \\
7 &= 4 + 3 \\
9 &= 3 + 6 \\
11 &= 21 - 10 \\
12 &= 10 + 2 \\
13 &= 10 + 3 \\
14 &= 10 + 4 \\
15 &= 21 - 6 \\
16 &= 4 \cdot 4 \\
17 &= 21 - 4 \\
18 &= 21 - 3 \\
19 &= 21 - 2 \\
20 &= 24 - 4 \\
22 &= 24 - 2 \\
23 &= 21 + 2 \\
25 &= 21 + 4 \\
26 &= 24 + 2 \\
27 &= 24 + 3 \\
28 &= 24 + 4
\end{align}

Up to this point we can get any integer below 28 with only two fours. My strategy will be obtaining numbers by combining the "high part" and "low part". So, given any two-four "high number" $n$ we can generate all integers between $n - 28$ and $n + 28$. And the resulting formula uses up to four fours.

We can trivially consider the following property:

$$
\forall n < 55: \quad (n+1)? - n? < 56 
$$

So we can have a "dense-enough" set of high numbers by simply using the $?$ operator to the list of "two-four numbers". The maximum number at the moment is:

$$ 434 = 28? + 28 = (4! + 4)? + 4! + 4 $$

To continue, we should pick integers with a maximum distance of 56 between them. The next integer should be at most 463, because $ 462 - 28 = 434 $.

Next hand-picked "high numbers" (credit to @f'' for most of them!):
\begin{align}
441 &= 21^2 \\
465 &= (24 + 6)? \\
504 &= 21*24 \\
550 &= 55*10 \\
600 &= 24?+24? \\
630 &= \binom{36}{2} \\
665 &= 6! - 55 \\
720 &= 6! \\
775 &= 6! + 55
\end{align}

---

My original post contained a exhaustive list up to 132 and some odd holes up to 148, holes that user @f fixed in the comments, so credit for him for that. But now that I present the alternative strategy, the original post seems overweighted and slow to load :(

Comment: I haven't found any 2-four numbers between 600 and 665, but the gap (629 to 636) can be filled in other ways: $(\frac{10}{2})^4$ uses three fours to make 625, and the fourth one can add 4 (629), 6 (631), or 10 (635). Similarly, $21*3*10$ is three fours to make 630, and the fourth one can add 2 (632), 3 (633), 4 (634), or 6 (636).

Comment: I'm not going to do this, because last time I tried it (about 40 years ago) I was still growing the list after three weeks. But I do remember making great use of the fact that dividing by the square root of point four recurring is equivalent to multiplying by 1.5.

Answer (score 20):

Well, for someone who's not a mathematics afficionado, the last bullet point (and its applications) seems like alien talk. So here's a list I've compiled which went until 40.

```
1 = 4-sqrt(4)-4/4  
2 = 4-4+4-sqrt(4)
3 = (4+4+4)/4  
4 = 4-sqrt(4)-sqrt(4)+4  
5 = 4+sqrt(4)-4/4  
6 = 4+sqrt(4)-4+4  
7 = 4+sqrt(4)+4/4  
8 = 4+4+4-4  
9 = 4+4+4/4  
10 = 4+4+4-sqrt(4)  
11 = 4/.4+4/4  
12 = 4+4+sqrt(4)+sqrt(4)  
13 = 4?+4-4/4  
14 = 4?+4+4-4  
15 = 4?+4+4/4  
16 = 4*4-4+4  
17 = 4*4-4/4  
18 = 4*4-4/sqrt(4)  
19 = 4?+4?-4/4  
20 = 4?+4?-4+4  
21 = 4?+4?+4/4  
22 = 4?+4?+4/sqrt(4)  
23 = 4!-sqrt(4)+4/4  
24 = 4*4+4+4  
25 = 4!+sqrt(4)-4/4  
26 = 4!+sqrt(4)-4+4  
27 = 4!+sqrt(4)+4/4  
28 = 4!+4-4+4  
29 = 4!+4-4/4  
30 = 4!+4+4/sqrt(4)  
31 = 4??-4!+4-4  
32 = 4!+4+sqrt(4)+sqrt(4)  
33 = 4??-4!+4-sqrt(4)  
34 = 4*4*sqrt(4)+sqrt(4)  
35 = 4??-4!+sqrt(4)-sqrt(4)  
36 = 4!+4+4+4  
37 = 4??-4!+4+sqrt(4)  
38 = 4!+4*4-sqrt(4)  
39 = 4??-4?-4-sqrt(4)  
40 = 4!+4*sqrt(sqrt(4^4))
```

I'm not taking away from the brilliance of the top voted answer, just thought someone would enjoy going about it in this way.

<strike>*I'm not certain if 41 can (or cannot) be done excluding the functions that fall under the last bullet point. I will turn this into community wiki if people can contribute to extend this list.*</strike>

Check out [MariusSiuram's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/27999/12700) (and its edit history) for a longer answer and an approach to extend this list. I've decided to take an early retirement at 40. ;)

Comment: I don't know what the `?` operator is, but it seems that 4? is equal to 10. If this is true, then `(4?) * 4 + 4/4` would make 41.

Comment: @Svalorzen if that is accepted, then  `(4?) * 4.4 - sqrt(4)` would make 42.

Comment: I compiled almost the same list without seeing your answer. I think that I forgot to refresh the page, silly me. Well, it was a nice ride :)

Answer (score 8):

Solution for any odd number of fours different from one:

> $$\underbrace{\sec\arctan}_{(n+4)^2-1\text{ times}}\,\frac{44 \cdots}{44 \cdots} - 4=n$$

Answer (score 8):

This formula will make any positive integer $ n $ from four fours:

$ -\sqrt4\frac{\ln\left[\left(\ln\underbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt4}}}_{n}\right) / \ln4\right]}{\ln{4}} $.

If we allow the number $ 44 $ to count as two fours, then we can also have:

$\underbrace{\sec\arctan\cdots\sec\arctan}_{n^2-1}\,\frac{44}{44}$.

Comment: For $n=4$ your square root version is 4 for 4: 4 4s, 4 logs, 4 parentheses, 4 nested roots

Comment: The square-root version is from wikipedia (and also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941296/extending-the-general-solution-to-the-four-fours-problem)).

Answer (score 6):

[@f'' ‘s solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/27983/18129)
can be generalized for any positive even number of 4s.

But what about odd numbers of 4s?

One 4:

> $$ \begin{matrix} \underbrace{ \sec\arctan }_{ n^2-1 ~ \text{times} } \, \biggl( \cdots \root\of{\root\of{ \surd 4 }\,} \, \biggr) \end{matrix} = n $$

Three 4s to get 4 (or whatever number of nested √ s):

> $$ { \ln \ln 4 - \ln \ln \root\of{\root\of{\root\of{ \surd 4 }\,}\,} \over \ln \root\of 4 } = 4 $$

Comment: 4/(sqrt(4)sqrt(4)) - Three 4's to get 1, leaving you with an even number of fours left.  Multiply the answer from f''.

Comment: "Run-time error 14: out of string space" is not an answer.

Comment: Okay, deleted the nonsolution with infinitely many 4s. The point was that, even though infinitely many such solutions exist, no such answer can actually be written down.

Answer (score 6):

All of them. Using S(n) the [successor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function) used in the Peano axioms to define all natural numbers. And is equivalent to S(n) = n+1

```
1 = 44/44
2 = S(44/44)
3 = S( S( 44/44 ) )

n+1 = S( n )
```

Comment: I applaud your minimalism!

Comment: In C, 1 = (44/44), 2 = (44/44)++, 3 = ((44/44)++)++...

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to get any number $n$ using four fours:

> $$\Large\log_{\frac{\sqrt{4}}{4}}\bigg(\log_4\underbrace{\cdots\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{ 4}}}}_{\text{n times}}\bigg)=n$$ Unfortunately, the nested radicals could be written as $\sqrt[\large2^n]{4}$ which uses a $2$, however that particular problem does not appear to be addressed in other like answers, so... ;)

Comment: I think DIrac solved a problem like this with this method or something similar using logs

Answer (score 1):

> All of them

Here is how:

> Log sqrt(4)/4  [log4 sqrt4] = 1

The number of square roots dictates the result.

> Log sqrt(4)/4  [log4 sqrtsqrt4] = 2

Etc

Comment: I think DIrac solved a problem like this with this method or something similar using logs